# NodeJS: streaming multiple files from readstream (gridFS) to show on frontend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs, nodejs-stream

I have uploaded multiple image files into MongoDB using "Multer" and "multer-gridfs-storage". I want to extract these files and show them as thumbnails on the webpage. I have tried to extract these files into ReadStream and storing them into an array which i can loop.

```
var streams = [];
    console.log(result)
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

        var gfs = Grid(conn.db);
        var campground = gfs.createReadStream({
            _id: result[i]._id
        });
        streams[i] = campground;
        console.log("   " + i);
    }
```

I want to pass these to the front end where they can be displayed, but they are not displaying. I tried running the following code in loop.

```
    var rest
    streams[0].pipe(rest)
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg' });
    res.write(rest);
    //      res.addTrailers({ 'image/jpeg': rest });
    res.end();
```

is not working. The following works but only displays one file

```
 streams[i].pipe(res)
```

I want to pass the array of images to my ejs file. The  streams[i] array is grid object and not the final images. How do i accomplish this?

Regards,
Gaurav

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer after some searching

```
    const bufs = [];
    readstream.on('data', function(chunk) {
        bufs.push(chunk);
    });
    readstream.on('end', function() {
        const fbuf = Buffer.concat(bufs);
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
        res.writeHead(res.statusCode);
        res.write(fbuf);
        /res.end();

    });
```

Comment: Hi gaurav, can you kindly share the code for your back end and front end, if possible. Thanx a lot in advance :)

Comment: Hi @CoderX, you can access the full project on https://preview.c9users.io/gtyagi77/webdevbootcamp/MissingPeople/v1

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you're still looking, but here what I'm using:

```
var gfs = Grid(req.conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
var fileId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
var fileName = file.filename;

//Create a gridfs-stream into which we pipe multer's temporary file saved in uploads
var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
    _id: fileId,
    filename: file.originalname,
    aliases: fileName
});

//Pipe multer's temp file /uploads/filename into the stream we created above.
fs.createReadStream(imgDir + fileName)
    .on("end", function () {
        // something
    })
    .on("err", function () {
        var msg = 'Erro enviando imagem para o  banco de dados';
        req.flash('error_msg', msg);
    })
    .pipe(writestream);
```